# How share changeable data between components

Tags: angular

I have 4 component.

> 1: Cities component
>
> 2: two tab - new install / new service
>
> 3: basic component

I want on click throw city id to new install/ new service. This is my code.

new-installation component - https://pastebin.com/raw/MvQjNyvS

common service https://pastebin.com/raw/jNTp6pfe

3: component where I want get this id and then subscribe example new install component

```
 cityId = 0;

 getCityId() {
   this.cityId = this.commonService.cityId;

  }

      getCityData(id) {
    this.commonService.getCitiesData(this.cityId)
      .subscribe(
        (data) => {
          this.citiesData = data.data;
        },
        error => console.log(error)
      )
  }
```

Comment: Check this documentation - [component interaction](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction).

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please make sure to add a minimal verifiable code snippet of what you have tried so far for others to take a look and understand your problem. For more details on how to create [mcve]

Comment: new-installation component - https://pastebin.com/raw/MvQjNyvS

Comment: common service https://pastebin.com/raw/jNTp6pfe

Comment: cities component https://pastebin.com/raw/5XJqziVY

Comment: when i change tab and return this tab then loads data